# Stencil Required for Through Hole Components

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, stencil

I was creating a pcb board that is mostly made of header pins that are suppose to connect to adapters. I was wondering if a stencil is required for soldering through hole components on a bare bone pcb.

Comment: A board containing mainly through hole parts will normally be wave soldered. The solder mask (or solder resist) on the bottom of the board prevents solder shorts between the component leads. So, no you don't need a stencil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the technology you're using for soldering the through-hole parts. If you're hand-soldering them then no, you do not need a stencil. However, if you are using [paste-in-hole technology](http://www.photostencil.com/pdf/intrusive_reflow_of_lead-free_solder_paste.pdf) (aka "intrusive soldering") then you might. There are a number of different ways to apply paste for intrusive soldering and if you do it by hand (use a syringe to apply the paste in and around the hole) then no stencil is required. Otherwise if the application of paste is automated, you probably will need a stencil. Note you may need a separate, thicker stencil for applying paste for intrusive soldering due to the larger amount of paste required for through-hole soldering versus surface mount.